# WPF add fileupload service from other winforms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am new to using webservices in C# wpf. I downloaded a webservice example using winforms. I managed to upload files to my server from that winforms application. Now I want to merge this winforms functionality with my existing WPF application. I can not find out how to get the "uploader" under web references in my winforms project to my WPF project. This is the code that the web reference "uploader" contains:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18034
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version 4.0.30319.18034.
// 
#pragma warning disable 1591

namespace TestUploader.Uploader {
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="FileUploaderSoap", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class FileUploader : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {

    private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback UploadFileOperationCompleted;

    private bool useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly;

    /// <remarks/>
    public FileUploader() {
        this.Url = global::TestUploader.Properties.Settings.Default.TestUploader_Uploader_FileUploader;
        if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
            this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
        }
        else {
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
        }
    }

    public new string Url {
        get {
            return base.Url;
        }
        set {
            if ((((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(base.Url) == true) 
                        && (this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly == false)) 
                        && (this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(value) == false))) {
                base.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            }
            base.Url = value;
        }
    }

    public new bool UseDefaultCredentials {
        get {
            return base.UseDefaultCredentials;
        }
        set {
            base.UseDefaultCredentials = value;
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public event UploadFileCompletedEventHandler UploadFileCompleted;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/UploadFile", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string UploadFile([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary")] byte[] f, string fileName) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("UploadFile", new object[] {
                    f,
                    fileName});
        return ((string)(results[0]));
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void UploadFileAsync(byte[] f, string fileName) {
        this.UploadFileAsync(f, fileName, null);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public void UploadFileAsync(byte[] f, string fileName, object userState) {
        if ((this.UploadFileOperationCompleted == null)) {
            this.UploadFileOperationCompleted = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnUploadFileOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("UploadFile", new object[] {
                    f,
                    fileName}, this.UploadFileOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnUploadFileOperationCompleted(object arg) {
        if ((this.UploadFileCompleted != null)) {
            System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.UploadFileCompleted(this, new UploadFileCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public new void CancelAsync(object userState) {
        base.CancelAsync(userState);
    }

    private bool IsLocalFileSystemWebService(string url) {
        if (((url == null) 
                    || (url == string.Empty))) {
            return false;
        }
        System.Uri wsUri = new System.Uri(url);
        if (((wsUri.Port >= 1024) 
                    && (string.Compare(wsUri.Host, "localHost", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.17929")]
public delegate void UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e);

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class UploadFileCompletedEventArgs : System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs {

    private object[] results;

    internal UploadFileCompletedEventArgs(object[] results, System.Exception exception, bool cancelled, object userState) : 
            base(exception, cancelled, userState) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Result {
        get {
            this.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary();
            return ((string)(this.results[0]));
        }
    }
}
}

#pragma warning restore 1591
```

Besides this I do not know how to migrate the settings from winforms to wpf. In my winforms:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="TestUploader.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <TestUploader.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="TestUploader_Uploader_FileUploader" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://xxx/videolibrary/Upload/FileUploader.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </TestUploader.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

The largest part of my problem is that I do not completely understand the structure and how the web reference functions. This is probably the reason why I might be phrasing my question wrong.

--Edit--

When I use add service reference the reference seems to be different than the original reference in my winforms. On the left my winforms tree, on the right my wpf tree

!http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8308826/screen.jpg

Comment: You using visual studio if so you should be able to add a service reference from within the ide. That will create the service reference classes for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add it as service referance. Web reference is an old version of WCF services, which  existed in .NET 2 In you WPF project you should add service reference.

Read http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/10/the-difference-between-ldquoadd-web-referencerdquo-and-ldquoadd-service-referencerdquo.aspx about their differences and how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I click add service reference in my WPF project I enter an adress: http://xxx/videolibrary/Upload/FileUploader.asmx. In the services box only FileUploader shows up. The original reference in the winforms project is called uploader which contains FileUploader, Fileuploadercompleted and Fileuploadercompletedargs. Is something missing now?

Comment: I think my finding finds support in the fact that the IDE can not find fileuploader in testapplication.uploader when i try to create a new fileuploader "TestApplication.Uploader.FileUploader srv" is there anything else i am missing?

Comment: @user1766412 When you add referance to your service, it just generates a proxi class according to your service settings. Web ref and service ref do the same thing in general, by the classes a different inside.

Comment: Thank you. I used FileUPloaderSoapClient in WPF instead of FileUPloader which did the trick. The UploadFileCompleted event is however no longer available and I would like to use FileUPloadAsync. Any alternatives?

Comment: @user1766412 You have to generate the proxi instance. After that you'll be able to use FileUPload like proxi.FileUPload(). And mark the answer as correct, if it helped to solve your problem